# Internet Explorer Tab Sync

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I am building a plug-in for IE browser. The feature i am working on requires to read the urls from user's open tabs and save it in a database. 
I do know how to read the URL from the current open tab, but if there are several open tabs I do not know the way to navigate through tabs so I could save the rest of the Urls.

Does anyone know any useful Api calls I could use that would allow to navigate through open tabs in IE browser?

Thank you.